# What is the REST request for clearing a user list on GoogleAds?

Tags: google-ads-api

I have a user list on my Google Ads account.
I can access it, but I do not know how to clear it via the REST API.

Do you have any idea or examples?

Here is the request to read the list:

```
curl -f --request POST "https://googleads.googleapis.com/v10/customers/1111111111/googleAds:searchStream" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --header "developer-token: ${DEVTOKEN}" \
     --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
     --header "login-customer-id: 2222222222" \
     --data "{ query:'SELECT user_list.id, user_list.name FROM user_list'}"
```

Thanks,
Nicolas